# Fill a list of arrays java

Tags: java

I wanted to fill a list of arrays in Java
I tried this in order to practice a little bit:

```
ArrayList <int []> temp = new ArrayList <int []>();
    for (int a = 1; a < 4 ; a++) {
        int [] array = new int [8];
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                array [i] = i*a;
            }
        System.out.println(array);
        temp.add(array);    
    }
System.out.println(temp);
```

This is the output I got

```
[[I@15db9742, [I@6d06d69c, [I@7852e922]
```

Please, why do i have this strange result ?

Comment: That's the default toString of an int array.

Comment: Solved or not??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`temp` is defined as `ArrayList <int []>`, that is, a list of arrays. In Java, when you print something, eg. by calling `System.out.println(temp)`, the object in question is converted to a string by an implicit call to `toString()`. `ArrayList` overrides `toString()` and prints each of its elements in turn. For each element `toString()` is also called. However there is no `toString()` defined for `int[]` so you simply get the object reference, ie. the funny-looking string `[I@6d06d69c`. To print the value of `temp` in a meaningful fashion, you need to convert each `int[]` to something human-readable. The easiest way to do this is to make use of `java.util.Arrays.toString()`.

So you could try something like:

```
for (int[] element : temp) {
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(element));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is that you are printing the Object class name representation then @ followed by Hashcode.

**Your Output:**

> [I@15db9742, [I@6d06d69c, [I@7852e922]

`I` is the Object Class representation

`Numbers followed by @` are Hashcode.

So, when you call this `System.out.println(temp);` , you are printing default representation of `array`. To get something meaningful and data from it you need to do like below:

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(temp));
```